# SETX command missing in Windows10

Tags: windows-10, environment-variables

In my **Windows10** laptop, I notice that **setx** command missing. Get error message

> "setx is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Any solutions to this issue?

There are scripts which use this command and those script are failing.

I am not mainly into sysadmin but Java programmer. Please suggest.

I am not sure though if its just on my system or anybody else on Windows10 notices this issue.

Comment: What's your current PATH variable contents?  At minimum, ensure `C:\windows\system32` isn't missing from it..

Comment: -1 why don't you search the hard disk for setx.exe  why not write a java program to search c:\ for it, or how about use the command `C:\>dir /s setx.exe<ENTER>`   And how about considering trying copying it from another computer or searching for it on the internet

Comment: Thanks for valuable inputs , C:\windows\system32 was not on PATH.  @barlop : posted question only after searching on Internet but yes, didn't tried well enough and all the options first.